# How to link OpenCV library in CentOS

Tags: c++, opencv

I got this error while compiling test file:

```
undefined reference to cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)
undefined reference to cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)
```

My code is:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int ImageShow() {
    const char* filename = "/home/users/wuchang.li/000001.jpg";
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::imshow("src", src);
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
int main(){
        ImageShow();
        return 0;
}
```

I've tried several ways:

I used:

```
g++ test.cpp -o getmask `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

and then used:

```
g++ test.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

I don't have right to modify file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf`

I'm sure my include path and lib path is correct.

Comment: Show a complete example with command lines used. Drop those screenshots.

Comment: solved by adding link path(-L/data-sdb/wuchang.li/MOT_model/opencv_usr_local/lib64) in compiling

Comment: @jack just add it in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @codekaizer [Never use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](https://gms.tf/ld_library_path-considered-harmful.html).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin wow! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you use linker `-L` flag it means that your shared libraries are in non-standard locations. That flag makes it link, but run-time linker `ld.so` won't find the shared library.

Along with `-L<dir>` use `-Wl,-rpath=<dir>` when linking shared libraries.

Do not use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, see [LD_LIBRARY_PATH considered harmful](https://gms.tf/ld_library_path-considered-harmful.html) for more details.

When compiling always use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to prevent bugs at compile time.